# Mongoose populate from nested schema

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I have the follwing schemas :

```
const Entity = new Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    accounts: [account.schema],
  },



  const Account = new Schema(
      {
        name: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
        },
        phone, address ,....
     
      },
```

and invoice :

```
const Invoice = new Schema(
  {
    number: {
      type: Number,
      index: true,
      default: 0,
    },
    customer: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Entity",
    },
    account: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Account",
    },
```

is the any way that I can populate the account field in the invoice query ?

```
await invoiceModel
      .find({})
      .sort({ _id: -1 })
      .populate("customer")
      .populate("account")
      .then((invoices) => {
        console.log(invoices);
        resolve(invoices);
      })
```

or I have design mistake? any help will be much appreciated

Comment: what happens in your

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your schema design looks fine but you are incorrectly chaining `then` blocks to the `await` return value. Try this:

```js
const invoices = await invoiceModel.find({})
.populate({ path: 'customer', model: CustomerModel })
.populate({ path: 'account', model: AccountModel})
.sort({ _id: -1 });
```

I have included `model: ModelName` for each populate in the event you need to register the model as it may not be in scope depending on your design.

Comment: Still same issue account is null. please notice that the account is a sub document in the entity schema

Comment: I thought you said "*is the any way that I can populate the account field in the invoice query*". This code will populate the `account` field in the `invoice` query. Do you also want the `accounts` filed populated in the `Entity` documents? Do you have an accounts collection in the database? If you don't you cant' do the populate.

Comment: as you mentioned, i don not have an `account` collection in the database so i may consider changing my schema design, thanks for the answer

Comment: Yes unfortunately your `accounts` array in your `Entity` schema is essentially a subdocument that is **embedded** in the top-level document. In contrast, within in your `Invoice` schema each `account` is a **referenced** document and are separate top-level documents. My advice would be to change your `Entity` schema so that the `accounts` array is an array of referenced documents (ObjectIds). Good luck with your project.

Comment: thanks man, this is exactly what i thought of